# Increase value of last json array object

Tags: arrays, json, api, restlet

I am building an API post from the results of a GET and would like to add to the value of the last object in a node.

I am using length to find the last value in the json

The incoming body:

```
[{"batchId":"1005"},{"batchId":"1009"},...]
```

To parse out the last value in the "batchId" array:

```
"body".jsonPath("$.batchId[(@.length-1)]")}
```

this does return the last value of the array

What I would like to do is take the last "batchId" and increment that value within my jsonPath to POST the next batchId.

Comment: Can you post the POST body where you want to append the value. 
LastBatchId = body[body.length-1].batchId // This will give you the value of lastbatchid
Now increment this 
LastBatchId++ // you can use this value

Comment: The entirety of the body is the batchID

{
  "batchId": "string"
}